# Shuttle mode alternative in audio editor?

Tags: audio-editor, wave-editor

After reading this thread: [What audio editor are you using?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/15880/what-audio-editor-are-you-using), I was dooing a little research to choose the best audio editor for mac and pc (I need a cross-platform editor). But I would love to have the Pro Tools shuttle mode workflow in an audio editor. There is a scrub function in Adobe Audition, but it's not that powerfull like shuttle mode. Maybe somebody found that function in an audio editor?

Answer (score 1):

**Reaper**, hands down the most flexible editor and also with fully configurable scrub modes.
Cross-platform is just the beginning of the benefits.

www.reaper.fm

Cheers.